Проблемы с кешированием плагина Flying Press
Использую плагин на дефолтных настройках, ничего не добавлял - не убирал. Как только активируешь плагин, всё просто летает, как админа, так и клиента. Как только пройдет время и количество страниц кешируемых увеличится, так начинает просто лагать. Причем если плагин перезагрузить, то проблема пропадает и он снова шустренько отдаёт все страницы. Кто знает, с чем это может быть связано? Как таковой нагрузки на сервак нет, но чуть цпу поджирает, а в остальном памяти хватает, диск не нагружен. По логам смотрел (frontend errors) и debug.log - тоже ничего такого.

https://i.imgur.com/jaafzTD.png - и работает отлично

Надо смотреть, что в network браузера. Если там ок - то профилировать.

Зачем использовать /непонятный/ плагин, если без него "всё летает"?
А так, по симптомам - медленные ресурсы для кеширования (если кеширование в файлы кеширование - диски, в БД - БД, итд)

Без него работает средне, обычные запросы без кеширования.  С ним летает, но до тех пор пока не закеширует страниц 200, потом начинает тупить так, что без кеширования реально быстрее, чем  с ним. До этого использовал WP-Rocket, кешировал нормально, но не сказать, что прям пулей отдавал, но работал стабильно, без всех этих приколюх с фризами. Сменил чисто из-за того, что новый плагин прям моментально отдавал, пока косяки не пошли.

Отличный плагин, намного быстрее прочих, использую на многих сайтах.

@KAGGDesign уже после ответа я пошел его гуглить, тк первый раз его вижу. Не знаю чем он тебе приглянулся - у него основная задача - говно типа минификации. А кеширование только в файлы. Во всяком случае я так понял из описалова на оф сайте и паре других ресурсах. (чего только стоит слово "ускорение" в лозунгах  - сразу понятно на кого рассчитано :) )

@SeVlad он работает реально лучше и быстрее других плагинов. А его функция предзагрузки страниц по ссылкам позволяет открывать ссылки мгновенно.
